# Does '几个运动员应该尽到自己的努力了，' have a critical tone in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

谈谈的是‘2008年的现代五项世界锦标赛。

这次比赛成绩不是很好，整个冬训主要是以基本功的训练为主，所以关于实战训练方面，冬训抓得不是太多。在这次比赛当中，几个运动员应该尽到自己的努力了，但是有个别项目，个别人出现了问题。

Does the phrase below have a critical tone?

几个运动员应该尽到自己的努力了，
I suppose / guess some （几个） of our participants must have tried their best,

Comment: 應該沒有批評的意思。
因為這句的重點是後面的「个别人出现了问题」。
所以「几个运动员应该尽到自己的努力了」只是用來凸顯後句。
簡單講，就是：「大多可以，只是某人......」。

Answer (score 3):

“几个运动员应该尽到自己的努力了” here is to add an reason/excuse before saying the bad result (但是有个别项目，个别人出现了问题。).

I think the author feel sorry to say the bad result, so he put an positive thing and praise our 运动员 first before addressing the bad result.

In English, there is a phrase “not to rain on your parade”. I think they are the same kind of idea.

Answer (score 2):

> *Does the phrase below have a critical tone?*
>
> 几个运动员应该尽到自己的努力了， I suppose / guess some （几个） of our participants must have tried their best,

Yes, it does have a critical tone

几个运动员 means "**a few** athletes"

应该 here means "likely"

尽到自己的努力了 = " had tried their best"

What he actually wanted to say was "**most of them** had not tried their best"

(He didn't want to say most of them were bad directly, so he turned it around and said a few of them were good. It is like saying someone have a good heart to avoid answering is he ugly or not--of course he is ugly!)

The following sentence:

> 但是有个别项目，个别人出现了问题。
>
> But there are particular individuals having problems in particular events.

He had made an understatement. Again, to avoid calling out most of them directly-- He didn't make it clear that these 'particular individuals' happens to be 'most of them'

Comment: Well, it's hard to say whether it's a criticism or not. We need more contexts to support it. "个别人出现了问题。" could be lots of reasons, not merely they were not trying their best. It could be aforementioned "整个冬训主要是以基本功的训练为主，所以关于实战训练方面，冬训抓得不是太多". Also, 出现了问题的人 could be some of 几个运动员(应该尽到自己的努力了). I would take it as a postmortem rather than a criticism without further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

几个运动员应该尽到自己的努力了

Means   it should be anticipated that the athletes have already worked their butts off (with the implication that the final result is far from satisfactory but no one is to blame)

Answer (score 0):

The whole sentences are anything but empty words that often appear in any many interviews.  It is typical "the sportsmen try their best".

You just can't tell the reporter that ask stupid question, "shits happens, f*ck off"